# PHP : Select from Database

Tags: php

thank you for reading.
I'm having a little problem with the next sentence:

```
$nats = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM reportSatus WHERE reportId = ". $_POST['id']);
$rnat = mysql_fetch_array($nats);
```

With print_r($rnat) :

```
Array(
[0] => 1
[id] => 1
[1] => Poca contaminacion
[name] => Poca contaminacion
[2] => 1
[reportId] => 1)
```

But in the database with the same sentence is:

```
id            name
1       Poca contaminacion
2       Mucha contaminacion
```

Any idea what can it be? Thank you in advance ~

Comment: You've fetched a row only once - thus you're getting a one row. If you checked the documentation you would see how it's supposed to use it if you want to fetch multiple rows.

Comment: `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($nats)){
echo $row['name']
}`

Comment: What's the problem? What do you want to achieve? Because I can see two things that might be confusing for novice PHP/mysqli users here. Besides, this is so dangerous, `". $_POST['id']`. Read about [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
echo '<table><tr><th>id</th><th>name</th></tr>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($nats)) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$row['id']}</td><td>{$row['name']}</td></tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Now it prints : Array ( [0] => 2 [id] => 2 [1] => Mucha contaminacion [name] => Mucha contaminacion )

Comment: ok, try updated code above - is that closer to what you want?

Comment: tried. No luck. Print this, missing the first one: 2 Mucha contaminacion

Comment: try $nats = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM reportSatus"); and see if they all come out

Comment: ok, good. Are you sure that the record "id = 2, name = Mucha contaminacion" actually has a reportId = 1?

Comment: Yes. Btw, I fixed it somehow. I erased below the query : $rnat = mysql_fetch_array($nats); And it works now... No idea. Thanks for your time.

Comment: ah, did you have `$rnat = mysql_fetch_array($nats);` as well as the loop? if so that will have read in the first record and moved the pointer onto the next record before we started printing them out.

Answer (score 0):

[**From documentation**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows. The type of returned array depends on how result_type is defined. By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices. Using MYSQL_ASSOC, you only get associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), using MYSQL_NUM, you only get number indices (as mysql_fetch_row() works).

That's actually the way it works, if you need more rows to be returned you will need to loop throw the records

```
while($rnat = mysql_fetch_array($nats))
{
    //print here
}
```

Comment: Still missing values. Prints: Array ( [0] => 2 [id] => 2 [1] => Mucha contaminacion [name] => Mucha contaminacion )

Comment: It returns what you are selecting, if you loop then it will return all available records for your select